# Why onreadystatechange fails when trying to POST data to php script?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have the following Javascript code using Ajax to send input data to database from form in notebook.php when submit button is clicked. Function called `addNote()` should handle the Ajax operation by posting the data to `add.php`.

For some reason this doesn't work. `onreadystate` function seems to fail and response text from `add.php` is never received to variable `res`. I have no idea why. Is there something missing from the code or what?

Here are the contents of files notebook.js, notebook.php.

`notebook.js`:

```
function addNote() {
    ...
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) { // compelete & OK
            var res = xhr.responseText;
        }
    }

    var notetext = document.getElementById("notetext").value;
    xhr.open("POST", "add.php", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send("notetext=" + notetext);
} 

function main() {

    $("#submitbtn").click(function() {
        addNote();
    });
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

`notebook.php`:

```
...
<body>
    <h1>Notebook</h1>

    <div class="input">
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="notetext" id="notetext">
            <input type="submit" value="Add" id="submitbtn">
        </form>
    </div>

    <ul>
        <?php
            // add stuff to list
        ?>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not cancel the click of the submit button so the form submits the page.

```
$("#submitbtn").click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();  //cancel the form submission by cancelling the click action. 
    addNote();
});
```

Comment: Now it adds notes to database but I have to refresh to make them show up. How to fix this?

Comment: The page does not magically update, you need to update it. Return the new code and set the innerHTML/append the new items.